# "Format" menu in TextEdit or Note with changed shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, big-sur

Something happend in my Big Sur macOS and the shortcut for "Format" -> "Text" -> "Center" is changed in the "down" key!

[image]

So for example every time I press the down key in TextEdit or Note (and I suppose in every app that use these system menus) I got the text centered instead of move the cursor down.

I tried to restore default shortcuts and nothing changed. Rebooted, nothing. CMD + OPT + P + R not resolved the issue...

—— update ——

I reset the shortcut in sys pref -> keyboard, but with no success. I tried with another account on the mac and the problem is the same. So it’s not a user setting, but a system one.

—— possible workaround——

In the apple forum someone had the same problem related to BigSur update:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252054589

Any idea how to restore system shortcut for this type of menu?

Comment: No Mac handy but something like Sys Pref / Keyboard / Application Shortcuts would be where I would look first. Check all applications and specific ones.

Comment: Follow what @Andyroo

Answer (score 0):

Follow what @Andyroo said, it's mostly likely that a shortcut was set.

`System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts`

Comment: There aren’t application shortcuts set. I reset all the shortcut in sys pref -> keyboard ...

Comment: Try adding a shortcut to change the key command if there is nothing there.

I'm wondering if this is a language related issue.

Comment: Yes, as discussed in the Apple Support forum, it seems to be a BigSur language related issue. I set a shortcut.